# Eclipse classpath entries changing from var to absolute paths

Tags: java, eclipse, niagara-ax

I don't understand why Eclipse is doing this but it is driving me mad!

My classpaths are originally declared something like this:

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="NIAGARA_HOME/modules/baja.jar"/>
```

At some point, either Eclipse or TFS convert these to absolute paths, like this:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Niagara/3.6.47-dev/modules/baja.jar"/>
```

This usually happens when someone else, who has a different folder structure to me, imports and edits the project and then pends it back to TFS. Surely, Eclipse should recognise it is a variable path and if it can't resolve the variable, flag as a problem. But somehow it is resolving the variable and converting the paths to absolute paths.

I have searched for an answer to this both on Stack and the wider internet but I can't find much which explains why this is happening and how to stop it, so I apologise if it has been brought up before.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not TFS; TFS just takes the files you commit as-is.

Comment: @DanielMann Yes, I agree. So it must be an Eclipse thing...